# How can I trace out modification of stored procedure with TSQL Command in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Using this query I can get created date and last modified date:

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date ,*
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
```

But how can I get command?

Comment: What "command" are you trying to "trace out"? Do you want to query the source code of the Stored Procedures you are returning, or are you trying to inspect the modifications which were made to each procedure on the `modify_date`?

Comment: I want source code of the stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this, for example:

```
SELECT  o.name, 
        o.create_date, 
        o.modify_date,
        m.[definition]
FROM sys.objects o
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON o.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
WHERE o.[type] = 'P'
```

You can also use `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` or `sp_helptext` if you'd prefer - the latter returns a table with one row for each line of the source code for the specified object.

You'll find some more information on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345443.aspx).